# Symfony2 + Doctrine : Tool for generating relations between entities

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

when I want to create a new entity I use the following command :

> php app/console doctrine:generate entity

But this will help me only to generate attributes with their setters and getters

Is there a way that helps me to generate also relations between entities ( OneToMany , and ManyToOne for example ) ?

Comment: You can configure templates/macros in your IDE, I think that's the simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try ORM Designer. It's not cheap, but helpful:

http://www.orm-designer.com

Comment: ORM Designer was renamed to Skipper and it's available on http://www.skipper18.com now.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question after 5 years. I am doing it because I juste used symfony4's tool for generating entities and It's super awesome. A big up to the community for making such great tools.

In symfony4 you juste have to execute the commande `bin/console make:entity` then choose your field name `user` per say, then for the type choose `relation` and a wizard will take trought the process and generates all the needed code for you !

An example of how it amazed me :

```
New property name (press <return> to stop adding fields):
 > user

Field type (enter ? to see all types) [string]:
 > relation

 What class should this entity be related to?:
 > User

What type of relationship is this?
 ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Type         Description                                                     
 ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
  ManyToOne    Each Statement relates to (has) one User.                       
               Each User can relate/has to (have) many Statement objects       

  OneToMany    Each Statement relates can relate to (have) many User objects.  
               Each User relates to (has) one Statement                        

  ManyToMany   Each Statement relates can relate to (have) many User objects.  
               Each User can also relate to (have) many Statement objects      

  OneToOne     Each Statement relates to (has) exactly one User.               
               Each User also relates to (has) exactly one Statement.          
 ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

 Relation type? [ManyToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany, OneToOne]:
 > ManyToOne

 Is the Statement.user property allowed to be null (nullable)? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 Do you want to add a new property to User so that you can access/update Statement objects from it - e.g. $user->getStatements()? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 A new property will also be added to the User class so that you can access the related Statement objects from it.

 New field name inside User [statements]:
 > 

 updated: src/Entity/Statement.php
 updated: src/Entity/User.php

 Add another property? Enter the property name (or press <return> to stop adding fields):
 > 



  Success! 


 Next: When you're ready, create a migration with make:migration
```