# Can Symfony2 generate:doctrine:entity generate entity with one-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I suppose the answer is no but I am asking to be sure. 
SensioGeneratorBundle contains a command to generate entities. Do you know if it can generate the mappings for a one2Many or Many2Many field? Is there any project that implements this?

The only example I found:

```
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post --format=annotation --fields="title:string(255) body:text" --with-repository --no-interaction
```

Many thanks

Comment: are you wishing to override doctrine library function?then there maybe some solutions available

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old... but this could help some people.

Here is a Symfony3 bundle that can generate Doctrine 2 associations, including a one-to-many relationship:

https://github.com/Remg/GeneratorBundle

> **Associations**
>
> - Handles all Doctrine2 association types (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany).
> - Handles unidirectional and bidirectional associations.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: *"this is still a right answer."* Can't judge that, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Well whoever downvoted then.. let's just people know this is actually a good answer. (i did not say "the"). I think the answer is clear enough now. Thanks for noticing me.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK the answer is no. I have already asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007985/symfony2-doctrine-tool-for-generating-relations-between-entities)  and it seems that there is no free tool that can do that. But if you want to pay : http://www.orm-designer.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround that makes the job perfectly, without any additional software or bundle to install.

You just have to edit the `DatabaseDriver.php` from doctrine like described here :

[Symfony2 Doctrine2 - generate One-To-Many annotation from existing database by doctrine:mapping:import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474121/symfony2-doctrine2-generate-one-to-many-annotation-from-existing-database-by-d/15474310#15474310)